# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".flexipageTabset>.uiTabBar.uiTabItem.title"}

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, salesforce

I am testing a lightning component in salesforce when I am trying to locate an element in it it's showing me an error.
This is the element:-

```
<span class="title" data-aura-rendered-by="1261:0">Family Records</span>
```

I tried with all the locator element Like XPath, CSS .its does not have an ID

```
WebElement Family = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".flexipageTabset>.uiTabBar.uiTabItem.title"));
        Family.click();
```

its giving me error after clicking on it:-

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".flexipageTabset>.uiTabBar.uiTabItem.title"}

Answer (score 0):

If the element is the only element on the page with the ClassName "title", you could just get the element by ClassName:

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("title"));
```

If the element is not the only element with the ClassName "title", but is the only element with that ClassName under its parent, you can get the parent element then the child element:

```
IWebElment elem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ParentID")).FindElement(By.ClassName("title"));
```

If neither of those methods work and  you have verified that the XPath and CSS Selector is correct, but you are still running into the issue, there is work around you could try but I would not recommend using it unless you've exhausted all other options:

1. get the parent element
2. Get all "title" elements under the parent: `FindElements(By.ClassName("title"));`
3. Store all the elements in a list and iterate through them until you find the element whose Text matches "Family Records".
4. When you find a match, store that element and continue with the program.